# mysql command out of sync when executing insert from celery

Tags: python, mysql, database, celery

I am running in to the dreaded MySQL Commands out of Sync when using a custom DB library and celery.

The library is as follows:

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
from furl import furl

from flask import current_app

class LegacyDB:
    """Db

    Legacy Database connectivity library

    """

    def __init__(self,app):
        with app.app_context():
            self.rc = current_app.config['RAVEN']
            self.logger = current_app.logger
            self.data = {}
            # setup Mysql
            try:
                uri = furl(current_app.config['DBCX'])
                self.dbcx = pymysql.connect(
                    host=uri.host,
                    user=uri.username,
                    passwd=uri.password,
                    db=str(uri.path.segments[0]),
                    port=int(uri.port),
                    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
                    )
            except:
                self.rc.captureException()

    def query(self, sql, params = None, TTL=36):
        # INPUT 1 : SQL query
        # INPUT 2 : Parameters
        # INPUT 3 : Time To Live
        # OUTPUT  : Array of result

        # check that we're still connected to the
        # database before we fire off the query
        try:
            db_cursor = self.dbcx.cursor()
            if params:
              self.logger.debug("%s : %s" % (sql, params))
              db_cursor.execute(sql,params)
              self.dbcx.commit()
            else:
              self.logger.debug("%s" % sql)
              db_cursor.execute(sql)
            self.data = db_cursor.fetchall()
            if self.data == None:
              self.data = {}
            db_cursor.close()
        except Exception as ex:
            if ex[0] == "2006":
                db_cursor.close()
                self.connect()
                db_cursor = self.dbcx.cursor()
                if params:
                  db_cursor.execute(sql,params)
                  self.dbcx.commit()
                else:
                  db_cursor.execute(sql)
                self.data = db_cursor.fetchall()
                db_cursor.close()
            else:
                self.rc.captureException()

        return self.data
```

The purpose of the library is to work alongside SQLAlchemy whilst I migrate a legacy database schema from a C++-based system to a Python based system.

All configuration is done via a Flask application and the app.config['DBCX'] value reads the same as a SQLAlchemy String ("mysql://user:pass@host:port/dbname") allowing me to easily switch over in future.

I have a number of tasks that run "INSERT" statements via celery, all of which utilise this library.  As you can imagine, the main reason for running Celery is so that I can increase throughput on this application, however I seem to be hitting an issue with the threading in my library or the application as after a while (around 500 processed messages) I see the following in the logs:

```
Stacktrace (most recent call last):

  File "legacy/legacydb.py", line 49, in query
    self.dbcx.commit()
  File "pymysql/connections.py", line 662, in commit
    self._read_ok_packet()
  File "pymysql/connections.py", line 643, in _read_ok_packet
    raise OperationalError(2014, "Command Out of Sync")
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong to hit this error, however it doesn't seem to matter whether MySQL has autocommit enabled/disabled or where I place my connection.commit() call.

If I leave out the connection.commit() then I don't get anything inserted into the database.

I've recently moved from mysqldb to pymysql and the occurrences appear to be lower, however given that these are simple "insert" commands and not a complicated select (there aren't even any foreign key constraints on this database!) I'm struggling to work out where the issue is.

As things stand at present, I am unable to use executemany as I cannot prepare the statements in advance (I am pulling data from a "firehose" message queue and storing it locally for later processing).

Comment: [MySQL Errors - Commands out of sync](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html): *"If you get Commands out of sync <...>, you are calling client functions in the wrong order."* (examples follow). Can you track which order you're calling `mysql` client function in?

Comment: ..or as least whether you're falling into one of the examples?

Comment: These are all insert statements, so I'm only calling one function.  I'm assuming (possibly incorrectly!) that celery opens a new thread to the database for each worker, so I'm failing to understand how the result can still be in use when every INSERT runs commit() - am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Do you require `pymysql`? It's still in beta and uses its own implementation for raw `mysql` protocol rather than the stock C library. It can easily be violating the connection states in some cases.

Comment: I was using MySQLDB (python-mysql) and I was seeing the same error, I'm wondering if I should be looking at https://pythonhosted.org/PySQLPool/ as a solution to this now...

Comment: Okay, so it's not a library bug.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it's an issue with my code, but I can't work out how to fix it! :)

My bet at the moment is that for some reason Celery workers are sharing a connection and therefore worker-1 isn't freeing up the connection quick enough for worker-n to access it again and post the results.

Actually, that could be a good way to troubleshoot it - start multiple processes with a single worker allocated to each...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70668/discussion-between-proffalken-and-ivan-pozdeev).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, make sure that the `celery` thingamajig uses its own connection(s) since

```
>>> pymysql.threadsafety
1
```

Which means: ["threads may share the module but not connections"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#threadsafety).

Comment: Yup, looks like this is the issue.

I'm running multiple celery workers as follows:

`celery -A <app> -c 1 -n w<n> --loglevel=info worker` and I'm not seeing the issue despite having processed thousands of records.

I think this is the closest I can get to a "fix", so thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Is the init called once, or per-worker? If only once, you need to move the initialisation.

How about lazily initialising the connection in a thread-local variable the first time query is called?

Comment: It should be called per-worker.  The connection is in a library that is installed into multiple venvs and then included into the worker code.  y understanding is that if I start multiple, single-threaded workers then I should be able to get around this?