# Why is Twisted's adbapi failing to recover data from within unittests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlite, twisted, python-db-api

## Overview

#### Context

I am writing unit tests for some higher-order logic that depends on writing to an SQLite3 database.  For this I am using `twisted.trial.unittest` and `twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool`.

#### Problem statement

I am able to create a persistent sqlite3 database and store data therein.  Using [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/), I am able to verify that the data has been persisted as expected.

The issue is that calls to `t.e.a.ConnectionPool.run*` (e.g.: `runQuery`) return an empty set of results, but only when called from within a `TestCase`.

#### Notes and significant details

The problem I am experiencing occurs only within Twisted's `trial` framework.  My first attempt at debugging was to pull the database code out of the unit test and place it into an independent test/debug script.  Said script works **as expected** while the unit test code does not (see examples below).

## Case 1:  misbehaving unit test

#### init.sql

This is the script used to initialize the database.  There are no (apparent) errors stemming from this file.

```
CREATE TABLE ajxp_changes ( seq INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, node_id NUMERIC, type TEXT, source TEXT, target TEXT, deleted_md5 TEXT );
CREATE TABLE ajxp_index ( node_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, node_path TEXT, bytesize NUMERIC, md5 TEXT, mtime NUMERIC, stat_result BLOB);
CREATE TABLE ajxp_last_buffer ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, type TEXT, location TEXT, source TEXT, target TEXT );
CREATE TABLE ajxp_node_status ("node_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "status" TEXT NOT NULL  DEFAULT 'NEW', "detail" TEXT);
CREATE TABLE events (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, type text, message text, source text, target text, action text, status text, date text);

CREATE TRIGGER LOG_DELETE AFTER DELETE ON ajxp_index BEGIN INSERT INTO ajxp_changes (node_id,source,target,type,deleted_md5) VALUES (old.node_id, old.node_path, "NULL", "delete", old.md5); END;
CREATE TRIGGER LOG_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON ajxp_index BEGIN INSERT INTO ajxp_changes (node_id,source,target,type) VALUES (new.node_id, "NULL", new.node_path, "create"); END;
CREATE TRIGGER LOG_UPDATE_CONTENT AFTER UPDATE ON "ajxp_index" FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO "ajxp_changes" (node_id,source,target,type) VALUES (new.node_id, old.node_path, new.node_path, CASE WHEN old.node_path = new.node_path THEN "content" ELSE "path" END);END;
CREATE TRIGGER STATUS_DELETE AFTER DELETE ON "ajxp_index" BEGIN DELETE FROM ajxp_node_status WHERE node_id=old.node_id; END;
CREATE TRIGGER STATUS_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON "ajxp_index" BEGIN INSERT INTO ajxp_node_status (node_id) VALUES (new.node_id); END;

CREATE INDEX changes_node_id ON ajxp_changes( node_id );
CREATE INDEX changes_type ON ajxp_changes( type );
CREATE INDEX changes_node_source ON ajxp_changes( source );
CREATE INDEX index_node_id ON ajxp_index( node_id );
CREATE INDEX index_node_path ON ajxp_index( node_path );
CREATE INDEX index_bytesize ON ajxp_index( bytesize );
CREATE INDEX index_md5 ON ajxp_index( md5 );
CREATE INDEX node_status_status ON ajxp_node_status( status );
```

#### test_sqlite.py

This is the unit test class that fails unexpectedly.  `TestStateManagement.test_db_clean` passes, indicated that the tables were properly created.  `TestStateManagement.test_inode_create` fails, reporitng that zero results were retrieved.

```
import os.path as osp

from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi

import sqlengine # see below

class TestStateManagement(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.meta = mkdtemp()

        self.db = adbapi.ConnectionPool(
            "sqlite3", osp.join(self.meta, "db.sqlite"), check_same_thread=False,
        )
        self.stateman = sqlengine.StateManager(self.db)

        with open("init.sql") as f:
            script = f.read()

        self.d = self.db.runInteraction(lambda c, s: c.executescript(s), script)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.db.close()
        del self.db
        del self.stateman
        del self.d

        rmtree(self.meta)

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def test_db_clean(self):
        """Canary test to ensure that the db is initialized in a blank state"""

        yield self.d  # wait for db to be initialized

        q = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;"
        for table in ("ajxp_index", "ajxp_changes"):
            res = yield self.db.runQuery(q, (table,))
            self.assertTrue(
                len(res) == 1,
                "table {0} does not exist".format(table)
         )

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def test_inode_create_file(self):
        yield self.d

        path = osp.join(self.ws, "test.txt")
        with open(path, "wt") as f:
            pass

        inode = mk_dummy_inode(path)
        yield self.stateman.create(inode, directory=False)

        entry = yield self.db.runQuery("SELECT * FROM ajxp_index")
        emsg = "got {0} results, expected 1.  Are canary tests failing?"
        lentry = len(entry)
        self.assertTrue(lentry == 1, emsg.format(lentry))
```

#### sqlengine.py

These are the artefacts being tested by the above unit tests.

```
def values_as_tuple(d, *param):
    """Return the values for each key in `param` as a tuple"""
    return tuple(map(d.get, param))


class StateManager:
    """Manages the SQLite database's state, ensuring that it reflects the state
    of the filesystem.
    """

    log = Logger()

    def __init__(self, db):
        self._db = db

    def create(self, inode, directory=False):
        params = values_as_tuple(
            inode, "node_path", "bytesize", "md5", "mtime", "stat_result"
        )

        directive = (
            "INSERT INTO ajxp_index (node_path,bytesize,md5,mtime,stat_result) "
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);"
        )

        return self._db.runOperation(directive, params)
```

## Case 2:  bug disappears outside of `twisted.trial`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os.path as osp
from tempfile import mkdtemp

from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks

INIT_FILE = "example.sql"


def values_as_tuple(d, *param):
    """Return the values for each key in `param` as a tuple"""
    return tuple(map(d.get, param))


def create(db, inode):
    params = values_as_tuple(
        inode, "node_path", "bytesize", "md5", "mtime", "stat_result"
    )

    directive = (
        "INSERT INTO ajxp_index (node_path,bytesize,md5,mtime,stat_result) "
        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);"
    )

    return db.runOperation(directive, params)


def init_database(db):
    with open(INIT_FILE) as f:
        script = f.read()

    return db.runInteraction(lambda c, s: c.executescript(s), script)


@react
@inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    meta = mkdtemp()
    db = adbapi.ConnectionPool(
        "sqlite3", osp.join(meta, "db.sqlite"), check_same_thread=False,
    )

    yield init_database(db)

    # Let's make sure the tables were created as expected and that we're
    # starting from a blank slate
    res = yield db.runQuery("SELECT * FROM ajxp_index LIMIT 1")
    assert not res, "database is not empty [ajxp_index]"

    res = yield db.runQuery("SELECT * FROM ajxp_changes LIMIT 1")
    assert not res, "database is not empty [ajxp_changes]"

    # The details of this are not important.  Suffice to say they (should)
    # conform to the DB schema for ajxp_index.
    test_data = {
        "node_path": "/this/is/some/arbitrary/path.ext",
        "bytesize": 0,
        "mtime": 179273.0,
        "stat_result": b"this simulates a blob of raw binary data",
        "md5": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",  # arbitrary
    }

    # store the test data in the ajxp_index table
    yield create(db, test_data)

    # test if the entry exists in the db
    entry = yield db.runQuery("SELECT * FROM ajxp_index")
    assert len(entry) == 1, "got {0} results, expected 1".format(len(entry))

    print("OK")
```

## Closing remarks

Again, upon checking with sqlitebrowser, it seems as though the data is being written to `db.sqlite`, so this looks like a *retrieval* problem.  From here, I'm sort of stumped... any ideas?

## EDIT

This code will produce an `inode` that that can be used for testing.

```
def mk_dummy_inode(path, isdir=False):
return {
    "node_path": path,
    "bytesize": osp.getsize(path),
    "mtime": osp.getmtime(path),
    "stat_result": dumps(stat(path), protocol=4),
    "md5": "directory" if isdir else "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
}
```

Comment: Since everything down to sqlite client is pure Python, you can step through under `pdb` and see what actually happens when you run the misbehaving command.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, tried this as well.  The data is written to the database but the query returns an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it turns out that this is a bit of a tricky one.  Running the tests in isolation (as was posted to this question) makes it such that the bug only rarely occurs.  However, when running in the context of an entire test suite, it fails almost 100% of the time.

I added `yield task.deferLater(reactor, .00001, lambda: None)` after writing to the db and before reading from the db, and this solves the issue.

From there, I suspected this might be a race condition stemming from the connection pool and sqlite's limited concurrency-tolerance.  I tried setting the `cb_min` and `cb_max` parameters to `ConnectionPool` to `1`, and this also solved the issue.

In short:  it seems as though sqlite doesn't play very nicely with multiple connections, and that the appropriate fix is to avoid concurrency to the extent possible.

Comment: Then you probably want to explore your connector's `threadsafety` attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442419/mysql-command-out-of-sync-when-executing-insert-from-celery/28443089#28443089 If insufficient thread safety is the case, you need to protect DB accesses with a mutex or something.

Answer (score -1):

If you take a look at your `setUp` function, you're returning `self.db.runInteraction(...)`, which returns a deferred. As you've noted, you assume that it waits for the deferred to finish. However this is not the case and it's a trap that most fall victim to (myself included). I'll be honest with you, for situations like this, especially for unit tests, I just execute the synchronous code outside the `TestCase` class to initialize the database. For example:

```
def init_db():
    import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
    c = conn.cursor()
    with open("init.sql") as f:
        c.executescript(f.read())

init_db()     # call outside test case


class TestStateManagement(TestCase):
    """
    My test cases
    """
```

Alternatively, you could decorate the setup and `yield runOperation(...)` but something tells me that it wouldn't work... In any case, it's surprising that no errors were raised.

**PS**

I've been eyeballing this question for a while and it's been in the back of my head for days now. A potential reason for this finally dawned on me at nearly 1am. However, I'm too tired/lazy to actually test this out :D but it's a pretty damn good hunch. I'd like to commend you on your level of detail in this question.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct.  The only thing happening in `setUp` is table creation, which succeeds.  Furthermore, checking with sqlitebrowser reveals that the data is _written_ to the database.  This seems to be a _retrieval_ problem.

Comment: It was worth an attempt for 300 points :) in any case, I tried your updated code with some minor adjustments and I'm getting stuff back from queries: `[('ajxp_index',)]` and `[(1, '../init.sql', 2019, 'directoryd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 1496059483.446335, 'hello world')]`. I'm not sure if some of the tweaks had anything to do with the tests passing. I'm running Twisted 17.1 on Py2 and 3 and I got the same test results on both.